# quickblox - remove private (1 to 1) chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

Hi to everyone and first of all sorry for my english. Second, thanks in advance for your answers. I've been able to retrieve a list of current loged-user dialogs using:

```
[QBChat dialogsWithExtendedRequest:nil delegate:self];
```

and

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[QBDialogsPagedResult class]] && result.success) {


    QBDialogsPagedResult *pagedResult = (QBDialogsPagedResult *)result;

    NSArray *dials = pagedResult.dialogs;
    self.dialogs = [dials mutableCopy];
    ...
}
```

I've been able to modify dialogs where type == QBChatDialogTypeGroup in order to remove the loged user ID from them using:

```
QBChatDialog *selectedDialog = self.dialogs[sender.tag];

if (selectedDialog.type == QBChatDialogTypeGroup) {

    NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    extendedRequest[@"pull_all[occupants_ids][]"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(unsigned long)self.logedUser.ID];
    [QBChat updateDialogWithID:selectedDialog.ID extendedRequest:extendedRequest delegate:self];
}
```

This makes that the next time i ask for dialog list to QuickBlox all of them except from the one just "updated" are listed back. The problem is that if i use the same "extendedRequest" request when selectedDialog.type == QBChatDialogTypePrivate i always get Wrong permission from QuickBlox. Is there anyway to make that dialogs with type == QBChatDialogTypePrivate won't be listed again when i request dialog list from QuickBlox???
I hope everything is clear. Thx in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use **pull_all[occupants_ids][]** and **push_all[occupants_ids][]** for private dialogs, only for group

With private dialog there 2 users in it - you and your opponent. And you can't remove or add anyone else because it's a private chat, not a group chat

Comment: What do you need? remove occupants or remove private chat?

Comment: Actually i retrieve chat dialogs from quickblox using: [QBChat dialogsWithExtendedRequest:nil delegate:self]; and i show them in a tableview. It seems reasonable that the user can remove the chats he/she wants. When a user wants to remove a group chat from the tableview i use pull_all[occupants_ids][] and the next time that [QBChat dialogsWithExtendedRequest:nil delegate:self]; is called, the group chat is not retrieved. When the user selects a private chat i don't know what to do...

Comment: any suggestions Igor?

Comment: NSString *dialogID = @"theChatDialogIDhere";
[QBChat deleteDialogWithID:dialogID delegate:self];

Answer (score 0):

To delete a chat dialog,

```
[QBChat deleteDialogWithID:dialogID delegate:self];
```

Handle delegate (conform to `QBActionStatusDelegate`)

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(QBResult *)result{ {
    if([result isKindOfClass:[QBChatDialogResult class]]) {
        QBChatDialogResult *qbDialog = (QBChatDialogResult *)result;
        if(qbDialog.success) {
            NSLog(@"Dialog has been deleted!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh no, something wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```